# In SAS, What's the difference between LOWCASE and KLOWCASE?

Tags: sas

The SAS documentation classifies LOWCASE as "I18N level 2" meaning that it can be used for single byte, double byte or multi byte data. I would therefore expect that it would correctly lower case a UTF8 string (assuming my session ENCODING is UTF8) even if that contains multi-byte character sequences, and it wouldn't corrupt it by dealing with each byte individually.

Given that, what's KLOWCASE for? 
The other 'K' functions all provide equivalents for normal string functions that don't work with multibyte strings, such as KSUBSTR, KREVERSE and do on. KUPCASE and KLOWCASE seem different in that they appear to be no different from their non 'K' counterparts.
Perhaps the classification of LOWCASE as I18N level 2 is incorrect, and LOWCASE is completely unaware of multibyte sequences?

Answer (score 1):

I can't confirm that LOWCASE works as expected with DBCS, but I think that it's likely it does (given that it's indicated to here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/nlsref/63072/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1pca7vwjjwucin178l8qddjn0gi.htm
)

I don't think it did work properly with DBCS in earlier versions of SAS; 9.1.3 for example had much worse compatibility, not to mention version 8.  As SAS typically maintains functions for backwards-compatibility reasons indefinitely, this may simply be a vestigial function.

Comment: Yes, it's classified as I18N level 2. That was the starting point of my question. So you think it's likely that LOWCASE used not to work with DBCS, then they introduced KLOWCASE which was fully DBCS aware, then they changed the behaviour of LOWCASE on multibyte encodings to make it DBCS aware (thus actually making it backward incompatible), thus making KLOWCASE obsolete? It's certainly a plausible explanation.

Comment: Correct.  SAS is full of all sorts of things like that.  If you want a more definitive answer, I'd post the question to SAS-L (SAS listserv); there are more folks on there, particularly more who have experience of twenty or thirty years or more and would remember older versions.  (Also, some SAS staff read the list and might chime in.)